# For real scalars $\phi$ and $\partial_t \phi = \pi$, why can't the Hamiltonian have terms of the form $\phi\pi$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian

Suppose one has a real scalar field $\phi$ and its conjugate momentum field $\pi := \partial_t \phi$. If the scalar is free and using metric $(-+++)$, the action is
$$
\int d^4x\ \mathscr{L}_{\mathrm{free}} = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^4 x\ ( \partial_\mu \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi + m^2 \phi^2 )
$$
which means the free Hamiltonian is
$$
H_{\mathrm{free}} = \frac{1}{2} \int d^3 \mathbf{x}\ \big( \pi^2 + ( - \nabla^2 + m^2 ) \phi \ \big) \ .
$$

**My question is:** For what reason is it not allowed that $H_{\mathrm{free}}$ includes terms of the form $\pi \phi$? I can see how this is related to $\partial_t(\phi^2)$, and feel like this may be why, but can't quite see the reason.

Comment: Who says it is not allowed?

Comment: @Qmechanic Maybe it's incorrect to say its not allowed, but it is surely true that terms of this form are usually not written down in an action for a real scalar - why not?

Comment: A reason you wouldn't *literally* see the coupling $\pi \phi$ is that then the Hamiltonian would be unbounded from below (since the term $\pi \phi$ could become arbitrarily large in absolute value and negative if $\pi$ and $\phi$ had opposite signs). However there's no reason you couldn't have terms like $(\pi \phi)^2$. Sometimes you can remove these kinds of "mixed" terms with a canonical transformation, and if so  people may also prefer to choose variables where these mixed terms don't arise.

Comment: A term like $\phi \partial_t \phi$ would not be Lorentz invariant

Answer (score 0):

$\partial_t(\phi^2)$ is why $H_{free}$ includes terms of the form $\pi \phi$.